# Lagrangian of rotational degrees of freedom for a diatomic gas

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I'm reading David Tong's lecture notes on statistical mechanics and in the Diatomic Gas section, the partition function is divided into translational, rotational, and vibrational. Still, for the rotational part they use the lagrangian:
$$L_\mathrm{rot}
=\frac{I}{2}\left(\dot\theta^2+\sin^2(\theta)\dot\phi^2\right)$$
In the footnote of the equation, the author suggests going to his lectures on classical mechanics to the chapter on heavy symmetric tops to get more information. However, I haven't been able to understand why it is written like that or where it comes from.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a diatomic molecule of radius $r=1$ situated momentarily in the $x$-$y$ plane. The figure shows the situation.

The energy associated with rotation of the molecule about the out-of-plane $z$-axis is,
$$\frac{1}{2}I_z\omega_\theta^2=\frac{1}{2}I\dot{\theta}^2.$$

Now imagine that the molecule is also rotating about the $x$-axis with angular velocity $\dot{\phi}.$ Notice that the radius of rotation about the $x$ axis is not $r,$ but $r\sin\theta.$ Since the moment of inertia is proportional to the square of the radius of the rotation, the moment of inertia about the $x$ axis is $I\sin^2\theta.$ The energy associated with the rotation about the $x$ axis is therefore

$$\frac{1}{2}I_x\omega_\phi^2=\frac{1}{2}I\sin^2\theta\,\dot{\phi}^2.$$

[image]